# jQuery scroll-prevention plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin

This plugin is for article pages that has a very long main content (left side) and a shorter sidebar. When the user scrolls down mostly the right part will be white space.

What this plugin does is make the sidebar stick or make it fixed past a point and will stop sticking when it collides with the bottom part or a footer. The functionality will not work if the main content is short.

Anyway, I'm asking feedback on how to improve my JS code.

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

// Create the defaults once
var pluginName = "scrollMinUntil",
defaults = {
    article: null,
    topPadding: 0
};

// The actual plugin constructor
var Plugin = function ( element, options ) {
this.element = element;
this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options);
this._defaults = defaults;
this._name = pluginName;
this.init();
}

Plugin.prototype = {

init: function() {

    if($(this.element).length <= 0)
      return null;

    this.scroll(this.element, this.options);            
},

scroll: function(el, options) {
    var article = options.article,
        topPadding = options.topPadding,
        w = $(window),
        wrap = $(el).children('.wrap'),
        startingPos = wrap.offset().top,
        fixedPosTrigger = wrap.offset().top + wrap.outerHeight(),
        stopMovingPosTrigger = 0,
        staticMarginTop = 0,
        scrollTop = 0,
        elHeight = 0,
        stopMovingPos = 0,
        fixed = false,
        staticFlag = false;

    if(options.article.outerHeight() > 1500) {
      w.scroll(function() {

        // Calculate dynamic values
        scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop(),
        elHeight = wrap.outerHeight(),
        fixed = wrap.hasClass('fixed'),
        staticFlag = wrap.hasClass('static'),
        stopMovingPos = article.outerHeight() + article.offset().top;

        // Check if scrolling before or after the fixed trigger, set stopMovingPosTrigger accordingly
        (scrollTop < fixedPosTrigger) ? stopMovingPosTrigger = scrollTop : stopMovingPosTrigger = scrollTop + elHeight;

        // Making sure that fixed is triggered when scrolling pass the trigger position from the original area
        if(scrollTop > fixedPosTrigger && !staticFlag)
          wrap
            .addClass('fixed')
            .css({
              'padding-top': topPadding + 'px'
            });

        // Fixed positioned area, setting paddings and margins, and transition scrolling from the static area
        if((scrollTop > fixedPosTrigger) && (stopMovingPosTrigger < stopMovingPos)){
          wrap
            .removeClass('static')
            .addClass('fixed')
            .css({
              'margin-top': 0
            });
        }

        // Static positioned area, setting dynamically the margin-top for the element
        else if((stopMovingPosTrigger > stopMovingPos) && fixed) {

          // Calculate top margin to be added to the static element
          staticMarginTop = (stopMovingPos - startingPos) - elHeight;

          wrap
            .removeClass('fixed')
            .addClass('static')
            .css({
              'margin-top': staticMarginTop
            });
        }

        // Original area before the fixed position area
        else if(scrollTop < fixedPosTrigger) {
          wrap
            .removeClass('fixed static')
            .css({
              'padding-top': 0
            });
        }
      });
    }
}
};

// A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor,
// preventing against multiple instantiations
$.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
return this.each(function () {
    if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
        $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName,
        new Plugin( this, options ));
    }
});
};

})( jQuery, window, document );
```

Answer (score 1):

This part is pretty odd:

> ```
>     // Calculate dynamic values
>     scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop(),
>     elHeight = wrap.outerHeight(),
>     fixed = wrap.hasClass('fixed'),
>     staticFlag = wrap.hasClass('static'),
>     stopMovingPos = article.outerHeight() + article.offset().top;
> ```

The 5 assignments are separated by commas, instead of semi-colons.
It would be better to end each of the first 4 lines with a semi-colon.

This is even worse, using assignment in the right-hand sides of a ternary operator:

> ```
>     (scrollTop < fixedPosTrigger) ? stopMovingPosTrigger = scrollTop : stopMovingPosTrigger = scrollTop + elHeight;
> ```

It would be shorter and better to move `stopMovingPosTrigger` to the left, and use the ternary at the right-hand side of the assignment:

```
    stopMovingPosTrigger = scrollTop < fixedPosTrigger ? scrollTop : scrollTop + elHeight;
```

---

Inside the `scroll` function, these conditions and their negated values appear multiple times:

- `scrollTop > fixedPosTrigger`
- `stopMovingPosTrigger > stopMovingPos`

To reduce the duplication which may lead to errors,
I suggest giving these conditions a name by storing them in variables, like this:

```
var fixedPositionArea = scrollTop > fixedPosTrigger;
var staticPositionArea = stopMovingPosTrigger > stopMovingPos;
```

This way, instead of re-typing `scrollTop > fixedPosTrigger` multiple times,
you could use `fixedPositionArea` and `!fixedPositionArea` in your conditions.
Of course, `!fixedPositionArea` is not exactly the same as `scrollTop < fixedPosTrigger`,
but it seems to me this small discrepancy won't break your script.

Using these variables the code becomes:

```
if (fixedPositionArea && !staticFlag) {
    wrap
        .addClass('fixed')
        .css({ 'padding-top': topPadding + 'px' });
}

// Fixed positioned area, setting paddings and margins, and transition scrolling from the static area
if (fixedPositionArea && !staticPositionArea) {
    wrap
        .removeClass('static')
        .addClass('fixed')
        .css({ 'margin-top': 0 });
}

// Static positioned area, setting dynamically the margin-top for the element
else if (staticPositionArea && fixed) {
    // Calculate top margin to be added to the static element
    staticMarginTop = stopMovingPos - startingPos - elHeight;

    wrap
        .removeClass('fixed')
        .addClass('static')
        .css({ 'margin-top': staticMarginTop });
}

// Original area before the fixed position area
else if (!fixedPositionArea) {
    wrap
        .removeClass('fixed static')
        .css({ 'padding-top': 0 });
}
```

---

Some blocks are not indented well, for example:

> ```
> var Plugin = function ( element, options ) {
> this.element = element;
> this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options);
> this._defaults = defaults;
> this._name = pluginName;
> this.init();
> }
> ```

It would be better to indent the body inside a `{ ... }` block, like this:

```
var Plugin = function ( element, options ) {
    this.element = element;
    this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options);
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;
    this.init();
};
```

Also, since this is an assignment, the right-hand side should be terminted with a semi-colon.

Review the rest of the code and correct all the under-indented blocks.

It would be also good to use consistent amount of indents.
In most places you seem to use 4 spaces, while in others only 2.
I suggest to pick one width and use it consistently everywhere.

Comment: RE: separating variable declarations with a comma: This is usually done to save a little on file size, since your won't need multiple `var` directives. I have a love-hate relationship with this. I like seeing `var` because it's a good visual queue that a bunch of variables are being declared, but I do like the (miniscule) file size savings.

Comment: @GregBurghardt these are not declarations, but modifications. The variables are already declared, the lines are pointed out modify them.

Comment: You are right. It was hard to tell which part of the OP's code you were referring to, so I got confused.

Comment: The part after the `// Calculate dynamic values` comment in the OP's code. I added the comment now to my post to avoid misunderstandings ;-)